# Fire only a set of rules in drools

Tags: spring-boot, drools, kie

Hi I have been experimenting with drools and drools template. I have a few template files from which I generate rules. The problem is I only want to fire rules generated from a single template file. The fireAllRules() function typically fires all the rules in the kieBase. Is there is a way to fire the rules generated by a single template. I have seen something called Agenda group, but that fires the main agenda that is rest of rules when none of the rules in an agenda matches. Is there a way fire only a set of rules in my case the rules that are generated from a single template?

Comment: Why not put them in different KieBases?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas is that the proper way of doing in production?

Comment: It's the simplest way to do what you're asking. There's no reason not to have multiple rule bases in production -- I've never worked on a project with fewer than three distinct rule bases.

Comment: What would be some other ways of doing it

Comment: Control or agenda groups, as you mentioned. You'll of course need to trigger the specific group. This isn't specific to the rule template, it's just how rules work in general, so the regular documentation should cover this.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas The control can be done by salience and agenda groups can be used fire certain agenda. But wouldn't the same problem would occur of firing the main agenda in case no rules are fired? Also as u mentioned you have worked in projects with more than three distinct rule bases. What was the methodology used there?